# How to configure timeout properties when running an Apache CXF client by command line?

Tags: java, soap, timeout, cxf, connection-timeout

As a Java dev, I'm currently trying to isolate a connection problem in a legacy webapp (.war deployed on Tomcat9 on a new server, a RedHat 8.3) ; it does call a SOAP webservice through Java classes generated via an old Apache CXF version (2.1.2) almost 10 years ago. This works either on the old server (CentOS 6.5) or on localhost (MacOS Big Sur 11.6), but not on the new server where it ends up with a `java.net.SocketTimeoutException` being thrown.

In order to explain this the best way to the Ops team, I'm trying to build 2 command lines: 1 calling the webservice with `curl` (which perfectly works wherever it's run), the other 1 with java (which ends up in timeout on the new server).

To give you an idea, here's the `curl` cmd line:

```
curl -X POST -d @/data/myapp/payload.xml http://xyz.services.company.com/XyzService
```

with payload.xml being:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
 <soapenv:Body>
  <tns:xyzMethod xmlns:tns="http://xyz.services.company.com/">
   <field0></field0>
   <field1></field1>
   <field2></field2>
   <field3></field3>
   <field4></field4>
   <field5></field5>
  </tns:xyzMethod>
 </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Now, part of the generated Java classes, is this class with contains only a `main()` and seems perfectly built for tests purpose only (in my opinion... - I'm not keen at all with Apache CXF):

```
/**
 * This class was generated by Apache CXF 2.1.2
 * Fri Mar 02 12:51:52 CET 2012
 * Generated source version: 2.1.2
 */
public final class XyzServiceHelperInterface_XyzServiceHelperPort_Client {

    private static final QName SERVICE_NAME = new QName("http://xyz.services.company.com/", "xyzService");

    private XyzServiceHelperInterface_XyzServiceHelperPort_Client() {}

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        URL wsdlURL = XyzService.WSDL_LOCATION;
        if (args.length > 0) { 
            File wsdlFile = new File(args[0]);
            try {
                if (wsdlFile.exists()) {
                    wsdlURL = wsdlFile.toURI().toURL();
                } else {
                    wsdlURL = new URL(args[0]);
                }
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
      
        XyzService ss = new XyzService(wsdlURL, SERVICE_NAME);
        XyzServiceHelperInterface port = ss.getXyzServiceHelperPort();  
        
        {
        System.out.println("Invoking xyzMethod...");
        java.lang.String _xyzMethod_field0 = "";
        java.lang.String _xyzMethod_field1 = "";
        java.lang.String _xyzMethod_field2 = "";
        java.lang.String _xyzMethod_field3 = "";
        java.lang.String _xyzMethod_field4 = "";
        java.lang.String _xyzMethod_field5 = "";
        try {
            com.company.services.xyz.XyzDataBean _xyzMethod__return = port.xyzMethod(_xyzMethod_field0, _xyzMethod_field1, _xyzMethod_field2, _xyzMethod_field3, _xyzMethod_field4, _xyzMethod_field5);
            System.out.println("xyzMethod.result=" + _xyzMethod__return);

        } catch (InternalException_Exception e) { 
            System.out.println("Expected exception: InternalException has occurred.");
            System.out.println(e.toString());
        }
            }

        System.exit(0);
    }

}
```

Then the Java cmd line looks like this:

`java -cp "/data/myapp/tomcat-9.0.54/webapps/myapp/WEB-INF/lib/gen-cxf-services-1.2.3.jar:/data/myapp/tomcat-9.0.54/webapps/myapp/WEB-INF/lib/*" com.company.services.XyzServiceHelperInterface_XyzServiceHelperPort_Client "http://xyz.services.company.com/XyzService?wsdl"`

I tested it on localhost, works fine, just prints (besides DEBUG log messages) `xyzInput.result=null` (because it gets an *empty* SOAP response - due to the *fields* being set to `""`, seen with the `curl` cmd line - but that means the webservice is actually called).

Now, on the new server, it seems like the timeout is defaulting to `30` seconds (default value in the Apache CXF version running it - 3.2.7) but I can't find an explanation on how can I put a timeout-related property in the command line.

Is there a way to do this? Or is it absolutely impossible?

Thank you for reading me!

PS: remember, this is legacy code - there is no way to alter it (esp. as it's been generated a long time ago, released as a .jar file on our company repo, and we can't get our hands on the original source code repo in order to regenerate it - btw modifying the webapp source code is also out of the plan...)